# How do I restrict access to files with specific extensions in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, file-extension, file-access

I have in my web application an ADO.NET Entity-Framework *.edmx file.

When I browse in the browser (when the application is running) to an edmx file, it doesn't show the error page like when browsing to a *.cs or vb file, it opens the edmx and shows my model scheme to all the users!!!

How can I avoid that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this two ways; firstly in the web.config or secondly in IIS

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="*.edmx" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

Here's a link to a microsoft support page that details how to do it in the web config and IIS.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815152

Comment: Worth noting that this only works for the root web.config - Mehrdad's answer works for subfolders

Answer (score 11):

You should map the extension to the ASP.NET's `System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler` class in `web.config`. If you are using IIS6, before you could do that, you should have mapped the extension to ASP.NET ISAPI handler.

IIS7 Integrated Mode:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="MyForbiddenExtensionHandler" 
             path="*.edmx" 
             verb="*" 
             type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" 
             preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

IIS7 Classic Mode. Something like:

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
     <add path="*.edmx" 
         verb="*" 
         type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
     <add name="MyExtensionISAPI" 
         path="*.edmx" 
         verb="*" 
         modules="IsapiModule" 
         scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

IIS6 (after mapping the handler to `aspnet_isapi.dll` in IIS6 configuration):

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
     <add path="*.edmx" 
         verb="*" 
         type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

Comment: type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web"
System.Web at the end, threw an error. should be just type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler".

Comment: Updated the answer with the full name of System.Web assembly to make it foolproof. I prefer to specify the name of the assembly to prevent it to be accidentally loaded from another assembly if it contains a type with the same name.