# Setting separate default page for each directory in asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

My question is simple
if i have multiple directories with pages like -

```
/admin/adminlogin.aspx

/user/userlogin.aspx

/default.aspx
```

i want to set default page for each directory how ever i can set default doc for root in web.config but is there any way to assign separate for each dir ? i didn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do it from IIS. Go to IIS> your websit, set `default document` for each directories manually. it will add different config files automatically.

Otherwise if you are using single config the you can try `<location>` tag:

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045625/different-default-document-for-iis-sub-application)  fro more references!

Comment: can i do it in web.config somehow?

Comment: Have you tried the <location> tags as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045625/different-default-document-for-iis-sub-application

Comment: you need to google it , you will find many answer to your questions, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053696/how-do-i-restrict-access-to-files-with-specific-extensions-in-asp-net

Comment: it says path should be relative / virtual? what does it mean?