# Unable to retrieve .js files in application after using IIS Request Filtering

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis

So the Info Sec team at my company said that we need to prevent users from being able to browse directly to the javascript files that are in the app's Scripts folder.

The recommendation that I've seen elsewhere is to use Request Filtering which works; however, my ASP.NET web forms application appears to no longer be adding the js file to the pages that need to, thus a lot of the functionality is no longer working. All the app does is include the js file as so:

```
<script src="../Scripts/Common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here are several solutions I've tried that do indeed prevent me from browsing to the js file but the app seems to no longer be able to access the js files itself:

[How do I restrict access to files with specific extensions in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053696/how-do-i-restrict-access-to-files-with-specific-extensions-in-asp-net)

[Denying direct access to folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822173/denying-direct-access-to-a-folder-only-allow-through-app)

[Hidden segments blocking access from the server](https://forums.iis.net/t/1233879.aspx?hidden%20segments%20blocking%20access%20from%20the%20server)

The app runs under Anonymous authentication in IIS if that helps at all.

Comment: `So the Info Sec team at my company said that we need to prevent users from being able to browse directly to the javascript files that are in the app's Scripts folder.`  That is insane; your security team does not understand client-server security (or your Javascript is terribly insecure)

Comment: Attackers can see JS that runs on the client, no matter how hard you try to stop them.  You need to make sure that having that JS is harmless.

Comment: @SLaks The JS is harmless (even a standard Jquery file) but they are rating it as a high level vulnerability as Information Leakage.

Comment: You should get a better security team.  With that attitude, they are likely to miss more subtle actual vulnerabilities.

Comment: Different from many other programming languages (like C), JavaScript is doomed to be downloaded to client machines and seen by not only the browsers but also the end users (if they want). So it would be rather strange that your security guys asked for something as you stated. I hope you did not misunderstand them, but you should verify with them once again (and maybe let them read this thread and teach you more on what exactly they would like you to do).

Comment: @LexLi Yes, it turns out I did misunderstand. The information leakage occurred when a 500 error page from an MS Unified Access Gateway was produced when running a trace command on the effected urls (which just happened to be js file retrieval URLs)... the issue was not with the js files themselves. I've reverted the filter request to allow the retrieval again.